# How to enter parameters to function in form of a list or a tuple?

Tags: python, list, function, parameters

Is it possible to enter the parameters of function in form of a list.
For example -

```
list1 = ["somethin","some"]
def paths(list):
    import os
    path = os.path.join() #I want to enter the parameters of this function from the list1
    return path
```

Okay i got my answer but just an aditional question, related to this only - 
here is my code -

```
def files_check(file_name,sub_directories):
    """
        file_name :The file to check
        sub_directories :If the file is under any other sub directory other than the   application , this is a list.
    """
    appname = session.appname
    if sub_directories:
        path = os.path.join("applications",
                        appname,
                        *sub_directories,
                         file_name)
        return os.path.isfile(path)
    else:
         path = os.path.join("applications",
                        appname,
                        file_name)
         return os.path.isfile(path)
```

i am getting this error -

```
 SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [unpack the sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) using the splat operator(`*`):

```
path = os.path.join(*my_list)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> import os
>>> lis = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> os.path.join(*lis)
'foo\\bar'
```

**Update:**

To answer your new question you cannot pass positional arguments once you've used `*` in arguments, you can do something like this here:

```
from itertools import chain

def func(*args):
    print args

func(1, 2, *chain(range(5), [2]))
#(1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2)
```

And don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: Hey Ashwini can you help with my new question

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma You cannot pass positional arguments once you've use `*`. So, `file_name` after `*sub_directories` is throwing the error.

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma You can use `itertools.chain` there: `os.path.join("applications", appname, *chain(sub_directories,[file_name]))`

Answer (score 2):

Simply unpack the list using the `*` operator

```
path = os.path.join(*list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *-operator to [unpack the arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

For Example

`data = ['a','b']   os.path.join(*data)`

Gives

```
'a/b'
```